# Show data in real time with AJAX/Jquery/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am fairly new to PHP but was looking at this tutorial. http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/ 
I want to test a similar concept to display data from my database on a page when someone submits data via a form.
eg there is a page where you choose what color shoes you want and a page with a leaderboard to see how many times each color has been chosen.
I have no problem submitting the form but don't no where to start to look to get the contents to display on the leaderboard using ajax.  Can anyone point me in the right direction here please?

Comment: When you say real-time, do you mean instantly, or every minute or so?

Comment: Ideally I would like it to be instant (on form submit) as for what I had in mind, there might be say a 5 minute gap between an action (form submit), then 3 actions in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should start with this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Ajax With Jquery</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#txtValue').keyup(function(){

              $.ajax({
                url: '/ajax.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: "value="+$(this).val,
                cache: true,
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(response){
                    $("#leader-board").append("you choose "+ $(this).val + "color : " +response.count + " times");           
                }
              });

            }); 

        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <label for="txtValue">Enter a value : </label>
    <input type="text" name="txtValue" value="" id="txtValue">

    <div id="leader-board"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and you ajax.php file look like this

```
<?php
//if your data return result like this so you have to do this process
$data = array("count"=>5);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send you form data  and get your response in your div which have an id  'yourDivId' like below. You should to make a one more column 'countcolor' in your table . Increment it when a user request a particular color.

```
     $.ajax({
         url:  base_path + "/folder/test.php",
        data: "id="+id,
        type: 'GET',
     success: function (resp) { document.getElementById('yourDivId').innerHTML=resp;},
        error: function(e){  alert('Error: '+e);  }  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

After you submit the form, you need to get the pertinent data, echo it back (if you're using ajax, you want to echo is back using `json_encode();`), and then put it in the "leaderboard" div. e.g.

Action page for submitting to database

```
<?php 
  header('Content type: application/json');
  // after you've submitted the data to the database, get the data for the leaderboard
  $leaderboard_data = array();
  $leaderboard_data = your_function_to_grab_data();
  echo json_encode($leaderboard_data);
?>
```

On the page where you submit the form

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'insert/path/to/action/here',
  success: function(data) {
    $("div#leaderboard-div").html(data)
  }
});
```